# Dynamics CRM custom filter on lookup view not working

Tags: dynamics-crm

There are a few articles online how to apply your custom filter to lookup field. I thought there couldn't be anything simpler and yet..

```
function addFilter(accountId) {
//create a filter xml
var filter = "<filter type='and'>" +
    "<condition attribute='parentaccountid' operator='eq' value='"+accountId+"'/>" +
    "</filter>";

//add filter
Xrm.Page.getControl("my_lookup_field").addCustomFilter(filter);
}
```

I want to see in the lookup quick find view only accounts that parent account is set to specific account. Yet once I apply this filter no account will display in the view. I am really lost.

Comment: Which version of CRM are you using?

Comment: Did you debug and inspect the value of `accountId`? Did you try a *Advanced Find* with the expected value?

Answer (score 1):

You must also run a function on load of your form which calls your `addFilter(accountId)` function. Something like:

```js
function preFilterLookup() {
    var accountId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentaccountid").getValue();

    Xrm.Page.getControl("my_lookup_field").addPreSearch(function () { 
        addFilter(accountId);
    });
}
```

This will only work in CRM 2013 and above.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand, how this addPreSearch & addCustomFilter works. Whatever filter xml we pass will get added to the predefined lookup view definition on runtime. Check the contact record for right parent account Id, hard code it in your filter & see.

This can be achieved in many ways based on your CRM version. In 2015 MS introduced no code solution as 'Related records Filtering'. try this if you can see this option.

[image]