# How to resolve Query Builder Error in custom filtering of Lookup field?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I have a contact lookup field in accounts and I have added a javascript for custom filtering. I am getting `0x80041103 Query Builder Error` while clicking on the lookup.

My fetchXML looks like :

```
var fetchXML=
 "<link-entity name='ct_contactrole' from='ct_contact' to='contactid' link-type='inner' alias='ab'>
   <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='ct_account' operator='eq' value='{RecordID}' />
   </filter>
 </link-entity>";
```

I am getting the expected contacts through advanced find though. Let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: You should share the code, how you are using fetchXML, and what is the javascript code for custom filtering? so that, someone can help you.

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your CRM version, this can be achieved even [without code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141297/7920473).

You better check the syntax because only direct  `filter` can be applied in `addPreSearch`/`addCustomFilter` [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/addcustomfilter)

```
var fetchXML=
 "<filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='ct_account' operator='eq' value='{RecordID}' />
   </filter>";
```

Finally if the filter is based on deep filter from `linked-entity`, use `addCustomView` approach. [Read more](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=3656)

```
formContext.getControl(arg).addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, isDefault)
```